# subdirectory filename on html-webpack-plugin with dynamic imported chunks

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

`html-webpack-plugin` is capable of handling filename within a sub-directory. However, the default dynamic import seems to be breaking when using it in combination with subdirectory filename. I have tried setting up `publicPath` and output `path`, but such settings affect the path of all chunks. I have reproduced the issue with a minimal project below:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'example/index.html',
    })
  ]
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
console.log('root loaded');

import('./part2.js').then((v) => {
  console.log(v);
});
```

**src/part2.js**

```
console.log('part2 loaded');
```

The above config is correctly creating the html file with relative path main.js. Following is the generated tree structure:

```
dist
├── 0.js
├── example
│   └── index.html
└── main.js

1 directory, 3 files
```

But the dynamic chunk is loaded using the following script:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="0.js"></script>
```

which gives an error because it searches for the `0.js` as `/example/0.js`

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
```

What should be the correct method to ensure that dynamic imports are correctly loaded?